# change the background color of default home page

Tags: theme, css

How do I change the background color of the default home page?

Comment: Please learn CSS first. 
Go to w3schools.com and give a thought on CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your ftp and open `skin/frontend/your_theme_pack/your_theme/css/styles.css` file and find something like:

`body{background:........}`

Change any color/image here and save file.

Make sure changed file is uploaded/replaced in ftp.

If you only want to change `home page` background then add following line right after `body{....}` in your `styles.css` file:

`body.cms-index-index{background:....;}` (in your case `cms-index-index` might be different)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to cpanel and in styles.css under skin folder goto frontend and your theme and then css-> open styles.css and in body class write background-color:.... whatever color you want.
 Some themes providing custom css options there you can also write.